# C# create dir in %AppData%

Tags: c#, directory

I want create directory (if not exist) in path AppData/Roaming/test. But my code doesn't work, I dont know why. Can you help me?

```
        string path;
        path = @"%AppData%\Roaming\test\";
        path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);
        Console.WriteLine(path);

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

This code doen't create dir.

Comment: the method `CreateDirectory` returns value of type `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`. What do you get there?

Comment: What gets written to the Console?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

%AppData% is a [SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

change your code from:

```
path = @"%AppData%\Roaming\test\";
```

to:

```
var appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var path = Path.Combine(appDataPath, @"test\");
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really use `Environment.SpecialFolders` to reach special folders rather than explicitly hard-coding a path.

Something like this would do the trick:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "test");

if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```